# Displays currency value in US culture format

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatting, cultureinfo

How can I displays currency value in US culture format like $5,123,456.55. I know that I can do it using ToString method but don’t know how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution using ToString method

```
double cost=5123456.55;
Console.WriteLine(cost.ToString("C", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")));
// The example displays the output: $5,123,456.55
```

Answer (score 1):

**See Also:**

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)